# "No such file or directory" for /bin/awk on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, ubuntu-11.04, awk

How can I install awk in this version of Ubuntu 11? I installed it from Ubuntu Software Center and I cannot use it.

I'm trying to run an awk script:

```
#!/bin/awk  
Begin  
{  
print strftime("ora %H, %M , %S");  
}
```

and I cannot run it because awk is not installed.

> `./l4p1.sh: /bin/awk: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk` is not in `/bin`, it's in `/usr/bin`. To find out where you have `awk`, you can run either of the following:

```
which -a awk
type awk
```

Then, change your shebang line accordingly:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
```

… or, even better:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
```

The latter will just use the version of `awk` for the current environment, and is [portable across different systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang#Portability) that have `awk` installed somewhere else.

Comment: It's debatable whether `#!/usr/bin/env awk` is better.  It will invoke whichever `awk` command the current user happens to have first in `$PATH`.  That's *usually* what you want, but it can cause problems if a particular user has done something odd.

Comment: @KeithThompson I understand there could be problems with broken per-user installations, but that should rarely be the case. I'm just used to using `env`, since there are more advantages to it than possible issues.